# App crashes automatically when it runs

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
Shutting down VM
06-13 10:08:20.934 27283-27283/design.nxn.login_template_01 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: design.nxn.login_template_01, PID: 27283
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{design.nxn.login_template_01/design.nxn.login_template_01.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at design.nxn.login_template_01.LoginActivity.initializeControls(LoginActivity.java:63)
        at design.nxn.login_template_01.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:56)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

This is my build.gradle(app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "design.nxn.login_template_01"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

}
```

## This is my **LoginActivity.java** file

package design.nxn.login_template_01;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;

import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.Objects;

import design.nxn.login_template_01.Tools.CustomViewPager;

import design.nxn.login_template_01.Tools.ViewPagerAdapter;

public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener

{

```
private static final String TAG = BaseActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 420;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;

private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

private String personPhotoUrl;


private static final int LOGIN_FRAGMENT = 0;

private static final int SIGNUP_FRAGMENT = 1;

private static final int RESET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT = 2;

private Fragment newFragment;

private CustomViewPager viewPager;

private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;



@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    btnSignIn = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    initializeGPlusSettings();

    initializeControls();


    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

    changeFragment(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);



}

private void initializeControls() {

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent signInIntent =
```

Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

```
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);


        }

    });

}

@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

{

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        GoogleSignInResult result =
```

Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

```
        handleGPlusSignInResult(result);

    }

}

private void handleGPlusSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

    Log.d(TAG,"handleSignInResult:" +result.isSuccess());

    if (result.isSuccess()){

        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        String personname = acct.getDisplayName();

        personPhotoUrl = Objects.requireNonNull(acct.getPhotoUrl()).toString();

        String personEmail = acct.getEmail();

        Intent intent = new
```

Intent(LoginActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

```
        intent.putExtra("personname",personname);

        intent.putExtra("email",personEmail);

        intent.putExtra("personphotoUrl",personPhotoUrl);

        startActivity(intent);

        finish();

    }

}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {

}

private void initializeGPlusSettings() {
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
```

// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();
    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.

   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).enableAutoManage(this,this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso).build();

    btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);



}

private void changeFragment(int fragmentType) {

    switch (fragmentType) {

        case LOGIN_FRAGMENT:

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

            break;

        case SIGNUP_FRAGMENT:

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(SIGNUP_FRAGMENT);

            break;

        case RESET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT:

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(RESET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT);

            break;

        default:

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

            break;

    }


}

public void signUpClick(View view) {

    changeFragment(SIGNUP_FRAGMENT);

}

public void signInClick(View view) {

    changeFragment(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

}

public void resetPasswordClick(View view) {

    changeFragment(RESET_PASSWORD_FRAGMENT);

}

public void backClick(View view){

    changeFragment(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

}

@Override

public void onBackPressed() {

    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == LOGIN_FRAGMENT)

        super.onBackPressed();

    else {

        changeFragment(LOGIN_FRAGMENT);

    }

}

public void logInButtonClicked() {

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.login_button_click, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void signUpButtonClicked() {

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.signup_button_click, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void resetPasswordButtonClicked() {

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.reset_password_button_clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)  

{


 }
```

}

## Here is my **fragment_login.xml** code

```
android:id="@+id/content_login"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:background="@drawable/login_bg"

android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="0dp"

    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="98dp"

        android:layout_height="99dp"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"

        android:padding="10dp"

        android:src="@drawable/vidya" />


</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:layout_weight="1">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/email_layout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="50dp">

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/user_icon"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_email" />

        <design.nxn.login_template_01.customfonts.MyEditText

            android:id="@+id/email_edittext"

            android:layout_width="304dp"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_icon"

            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

            android:hint="@string/email"

            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

            android:singleLine="true"

            android:textColor="@color/white"

            android:textColorHint="@color/light_text"

            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />


        <View

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="1dp"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:background="@color/divider" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/password_layout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        android:layout_below="@+id/email_layout">



        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/password_icon"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_password" />


        <design.nxn.login_template_01.customfonts.MyEditText

            android:id="@+id/password_edittext"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/password_icon"

            android:background="@android:color/transparent"

            android:hint="@string/password"

            android:inputType="textPassword"

            android:singleLine="true"

            android:textColor="@color/white"

            android:textColorHint="@color/light_text"

            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />


        <View

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="1dp"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

            android:background="@color/divider" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/forgotpassword"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"

        android:text="@string/forgot_password"

        android:onClick="resetPasswordClick"

        android:textColor="@color/white" />




    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton

        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"

        android:layout_width="150dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"/>



    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="or"


        android:textColor="@color/white"

        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>




    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/button_layout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:layout_above="@+id/signup_layout"

        android:background="@color/navyblue">



        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/login_button"

            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:clickable="true"

            android:onClick="logInButtonClicked"

            android:text="@string/forgot_password">



            <design.nxn.login_template_01.customfonts.MyTextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="40dp"

                android:gravity="center"

                android:text="@string/sign_in"

                android:backgroundTintMode="multiply"

                android:textColor="@color/white"

                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_big" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/signup_layout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            android:gravity="center"

            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <design.nxn.login_template_01.customfonts.MyTextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="30dp"

                android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                android:gravity="center"

                android:text="@string/dont_have_account"

                android:textColor="@color/light_text"

                android:textColorHint="@color/white"

                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />


            <LinearLayout

                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="40dp"

                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"

                android:clickable="true"

                android:onClick="signUpClick"

                android:text="@string/forgot_password">


                <design.nxn.login_template_01.customfonts.MyTextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="40dp"

                    android:gravity="center"

                    android:text="@string/sign_up"

                    android:textColor="@color/white"

                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: seems like Your singinButton needs to be initialized.

Comment: The issue is in your activity code. You are calling setOnClickListener method on null reference. Put your activity code.

Comment: Initialize `SignInButton` and then `setOnClickListener`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Looks like you havent initialised the button. Check with your activity and java file.

Comment: I have initialized SignInButton in above code as SignInButton btnSignIn;

Comment: try calling your `initializeControls()` before setting your viewpagerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Call initializeControls(); after the initializeGPlusSettings(); your mGoogleApiClient not initialize and you are using it into your onClickListener()

Second Thing

You are using your button(btnSignIn) in your both function that initialised into one function which is initializeControls() so problems came into another function initialise your button into onCreate().

Change your code like

```
 btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

 initializeGPlusSettings();

 initializeControls();
```

}

```
private void initializeControls() {

btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(**mGoogleApiClient**);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    }
});
```

}

Comment: You are using your button(btnSignIn) in your both function that initialised into one function which is initializeControls() so problems came into another function initialise your button into onCreate().

Comment: check out my edited answer again. let me know if it works.

Comment: In my  project i am adding sign in with Google button and i have added it (in xml file and java file).Before adding sign in with Google ,project was run successfully.After adding sign in with Google Button my app crashed. i am confused. why??

Comment: use typecasting btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setSize(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Error Changed This is different Error due to you are setting SignInButton.setSize(int) before initialising the button

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{design.nxn.login_template_01/design.nxn.login_template_01.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setSize(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: This is your old Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Before calling any changes on View first you have to take care of initialising that view into onCreate() callback.

Comment: I have already initialized btnSIgnIn in onCreate() method.and then setSize is used in initializeGPlusSettings()